# Spring boot UrlFilenameViewController not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I am trying to route a view when I request a specific URL without any Model, so i am using the URLFileNameController to do that, below is my main class and bean declaration for the same.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class WebMvcApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
            @Override
            protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                return application.sources(CpiWebMvcApplication.class);
            }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            ApplicationContext ctx =SpringApplication.run(CpiWebMvcApplication.class, args);
            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();

            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) 
            {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }
        }
    }

//Bean Declaration -- declared in a separate class
   @Configuration
    //@ImportResource("*/**/Controller-Beans.xml")
    public class BeanConfig {

       @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            return viewResolver;
        }

        @Bean(name = "urlViewController")
        public UrlFilenameViewController getUrlViewController() {
            UrlFilenameViewController urlViewController = new UrlFilenameViewController();
            urlViewController.setSuffix(".jsp");
            urlViewController.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
            urlViewController.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);

            return urlViewController;
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping getUrlHandlerMapping() {
            SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
            Properties mappings = new Properties();
            mappings.put("*.do", getUrlViewController());

            handlerMapping.setMappings(mappings);
            return handlerMapping;
        }

      @Bean
        public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
            return new DispatcherServlet();
        }

        /**
         * Register dispatcherServlet programmatically 
         * 
         * @return ServletRegistrationBean
         */
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {

            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                    dispatcherServlet());
            registration.addUrlMappings("*.do");

            registration
                    .setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
            registration.setLoadOnStartup(-1);
            return registration;
        }
```

When I run my spring boot app, I get the following:

```
  2017-01-04 10:43:04.806 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration'
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.807  INFO 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration'
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.807  INFO 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration': initialization started
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.807 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@7f1abac0]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.817 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@621cf3e7]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.830 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@41e31325]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.837 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@46a1a74]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.852 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@56cd7abe]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.852 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServletRegistration]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.852  INFO 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration': initialization completed in 45 ms
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.852 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServletRegistration' configured successfully
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.879 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration' processing GET request for [/logout.do]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.894 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /logout.do
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.909 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/logout.do]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.909 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/logout.do] are [/**]
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.912 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/logout.do] are {}
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.912 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/logout.do] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@720653c2]]] and 1 interceptor
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.912 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/logout.do] is: -1
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.917 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServletRegistration': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    2017-01-04 10:43:04.917 DEBUG 24728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

The logs clearly states that my app is not able to find the view, but I am not able to understand where i am doing wrong, as when i declared a controller with a mapping, i am able to get the view.

```
@Controller
public class LoginPageController {

    @RequestMapping("/secure/main")
    //@ResponseBody
    public String getLoginpage(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="Uttik") String name)
    {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "unauth";

    }
}
```

I tried even declaring the beans in xml, still it didnt worked. Any idea where i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access?

Comment: I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/logout.do and localhost:8080/unauth.do

Comment: can you try mappings.put("logout.do", getUrlViewController()); instead of mappings.put("*.do", getUrlViewController()); ?

Comment: It didn't worked :-(

Comment: why do you have this in your urlfilenameviewcontroller definition?  urlViewController.setSuffix(".jsp");
urlViewController.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/"); so your url logout.do would be resolved as /WEB-INF/logout.jsp and unauth.jsp , are these files present in the correct path?

Comment: yes, /WebMvc/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/logout.jsp and /WebMvc/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/unauth.jsp

Comment: try moving the jsp's to resources folder and see if it works.

Comment: I have moved as suggested but still it didnt worked..

Comment: did any one tried this before ? I have examples using xml, but i didnt find with java annotations :-(

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I fixed it, it was simple !!!

Comment: its  the path problem and i have commented:   `//viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class)` in InternalResourceviewresolver and `urlViewController.setSuffix(".jsp");
            urlViewController.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
            urlViewController.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);`  in UrlFilenameViewController